Is collection always faster with zip files?
I am working with many XML files that must be transformed using XSLT + Saxon.
After some research, I found the collection function.
So I create this template:
<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
    <mydata>
        <xsl:for-each select="collection(concat('file:///', $collectionPath, '?select=*.(xml|XML)'))">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="//elementA | //elementB" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </mydata>
</xsl:template>

I have a folder with over 20k XML files with ~400MB.
When collectionPath points to the folder it takes ~60 seconds to process all the files, but when collectionPath points to a ZIP file (~40MB) containing the 20k files, it takes ~6 seconds.
Why this big difference?
Wouldn't it take longer to decompress the file internally to process the contents?
Would this approach be a silver bullet to improve performance?

This will depend on several factors, including the bandwidth of the file system where your XML files are stored. The lower the bandwidth of your storage device, the more that compression will help. But my guess is that the main factor is actually the speed of your operating system's file system to produce a listing of 20k files. Many file systems are not optimized for directories with that many entries. I wouldn't be surprised if you got similar performance with a single very large XML file (uncompressed)

A ZIP file mimics the file system breaking the file into sectors.  The zip file you are not opening the file and putting into memory, but instead tunneling into the file system.  The speed will vary depending on the type of drive (electronic vs mechanical)  The zip file is faster because the files are not fragmented and are packed before putting into the zip.  This is not the case when you add and remove items from the zip after creating the file. With mechanical drive the heads have to move which take time.  Packing speeds up time the heads have to move.

Fascinating observation, and I don't know the explanation. It would be interesting to see a Java execution profile for the two cases, to see whether there is any difference in activity at the Saxon level. Incidentally, Saxon-EE can be considerably faster for processing a large collection because it uses multithreading.

As to the general question, my experience is that performance anomalies like this often turn out to be due to some very unexpected quirk of the workload, and the results very often DON'T extrapolate to other workloads. But only experimentation can answer that.

It seems that XSLT merge statement will help you too.

The performance I mentioned was on Windows, then I changed to Linux. It took ~6 seconds on Linux for both scenarios: compressed and uncompressed 20k files.

As a matter of interest, Noah, what kind of file system is involved? Was it NTFS or something else?

@ConalTuohy NTFS for Windows and ext3 for Linux
